# How to login locally to Windows Server 2016 with a domain user account?

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2016, login

I have an instance of Windows Server 2016 which is setup as a Domain Controller. An application running on this server requires a domain user account that is permitted to login locally. I have updated group policy and added the domain user group to the "Allow logon locally" setting and run "gpupdate /force". However, I am not still not able to login locally with a domain user account or successfully launch the application.

How can Windows Server 2016 (running as a Domain Controller) be configured so as to allow for domain users to login locally?

Comment: How is the account logging on? As a service? Scheduled task? Some other way?

Comment: The account is logging on via an application launched via a remote application server program. When I try logging onto the server from the Windows login screen using a domain user account, the attempt fails with the error “The sign-in method you’re trying to use isn’t allowed. For more info, contact your network administrator.”

Comment: `When I try logging onto the server from the Windows login screen`. Logging on at the console, or remote desktop?

Comment: Logging in at the console

Comment: You probably need to include the output of the following command on the domain controller to confirm the rights assignment: `secedit.exe /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg filename.txt`

Comment: I have since demoted the server as a a domain controller and I am able to login locally with a standard user account. Perhaps Windows Server 2016 doesn't allow for standard domain user accounts to login locally if it is operating as a domain controller?

Comment: Difficult to say without the required information.

Comment: My question is, does Windows Server 2016 support logging in locally with a domain user account? If this is not a supported feature then there’s no point looking further at information which is specific to my machine.

Comment: Yes, it is supported.